# File Upload nodejs, angularjs : Form mistake?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, forms, upload, submit

I have a multer file upload which does nothing, it doesn't even give me an error. My opiniion is that this is a form mistake, that the html form can't tell the angular controller to send the http post to the nodejs

upload.html

```
    <form  id="uploadForm"  ng-submit="ctrl.submit">
        Select File1: <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().ctrl.selectFile1(this.files)">
        <p></p>
Select File2: <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().ctrl.selectFile2(this.files)">
        <p></p>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="ctrl.submit()">
    </form>
```

AngularJS Controller
ctrl.js

```
var file1 = '';
var file2 = '';

     this.selectFile1 = function(files){
               file1 = files[0];
               this.files = files;
           }
     this.selectFile2 = function(files){
            file2 = files[0];
           this.files = files;
           }
       this.upload = function(){
                 var fd = new FormData();
                 var file = self.fileArray;
                 fd.append('file1', file1);
                fd.append('file2', file2);
     $http.post("/upload", fd, {
                 transformRequest: angular.identity,
                 headers: {"Content-Type": undefined}
             }).then(function success(response){
                 if(response.status == 200){
                     console.log('success');
                 }
                 console.log(response);
             }, function error(response){
                 console.log(response);
             })
         }
```

NodeJS Backend
test.js

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
       destination: function (req, file, cb) {
         cb(null, '../uploads');
       },
       filename: function (req, file, cb) {
         cb(null, file.originalname);
       },
    });


var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).array('file', 2);
router.post('/upload', function(req, res){
      upload(req, res, function(err){
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
              return res.end(err);
            }
            console.log(req.files);
            res.sendStatus(200);
          });
});
```

I can save the files from html to the angular controller and save them to the form data but when I send the form data with an array of 2 files to the nodejs backend I get an empty form data in the backend.

**SOLUTION:**
in nodejs file changed `var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).array(...)` to `var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).any();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use onchange to select the file.

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectFile(this.files)"/>
<button ng-click="savePhoto()">Save </button>
```

In angular controller

```
 xx.controller('yourcontroller', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.selectFile = function (files) {
        $scope.files = files;
    };
   $scope.savePhoto = function () {
     var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append("file", $scope.files[0]);
      )) ;
    $http.post("/xxx/photos", fd, {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            transformRequest: angular.identity
          }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.image = data; // If you want to render the image after successfully uploading in your db
          });
        };
});
```

Comment: How can I make it with the form tag ?

Comment: I have not tried it but you can try to put the savePhoto event inside ng-submit and try, but  why don't you try it without form submit and see if it works.

Comment: Cause I don't know how to implement this "angular.element(this).scope().selectFile(this.files)" into my app structure

Comment: just add  $scope.selectFile = function (files) {
            $scope.files = files;
        };

Comment: just console $scope.files and see you will be able to see the details, it comes in an array, then inside savePhoto (here  fd.append("file", $scope.files[0]); ) you are appending it with your formData to send it to your nodejs

Comment: But my controller is on a nother page how can I access the controller with the onchange?

Comment: yes inside that controller just write these codes $scope.selectFile = function (files) { $scope.files = files; };

Comment: 16:01:44.568 TypeError: angular.element(...).scope(...).selectFile is not a function
onchange()127.0.0.1:3000:1
1127.0.0.1:3000:1:1

Comment: check it out same thing

Comment: gives me the error 08:10:11.442 TypeError: angular.element(...).scope(...).selectFile is not a function
onchange()1

Comment: added the controller name to the onchange function, now it works. Thank you very much. Do you know how I provide an upload for more than 1 files?

Comment: <input id="file" type="file" name="file"  multiple>     you will get multiple files in array in your controller then its the same way you did for single file

Comment: I want to make 3 <input > tags what do I have to write in the onchange part  ?

Comment: nothing   $scope.selectFile = function (files) {
        $scope.files = files;
    };  here the files should now come as an array of files just console.log(files); and see for yourself after multiple selection is done, also if my answered helped you i don't mind you giving an acceptance to it

Comment: with this.files[0] I get the first file but with this.files[1] it gives me undefined! How can I access the single files?

Comment: and  the this.files[0] gives me the last changed file, not all files! It only gives me one file.

Comment: just press ctrl and select multiple files and console that in your controller and see you will get the file object as this i just tried (FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2}). now if you want to select one by one then on every onchange you need to store them in some array maybe

Comment: Yes I want to select one by one. What do I have to write in the onchange? angular.element(this).scope().selectFile(this.files[]) did not work

Comment: so every onchange you get one file right so declare an array and push the files to it on every onchange

Comment: I know what to do, but I don't know how to get it work what do I have to write in the 3 different inputs for my 3 upload files ? So I think I have to change the onchange part but what do I have to write in it. Tried some out but onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectFile(this.files[1])" for first upload input field did not work. Can you pls help? Or have you any idea how to get this done.

Comment: <input type="file" multiple name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this.files)" multiple/>
        <input type="file" multiple name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this.files)" multiple/>

Comment: and in controller.        $scope.files1 = [];
    $scope.fileNameChanged = function (files) {
     console.log(files[0]);
      $scope.files1.push(files[0]);
       console.log($scope.files1);
        $scope.files = files;
    };

Comment: Thank you that worked. But now I have the problem that the file array is empty when it arrives at my NodeJS backend. Why does this happen?

Comment: var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("file", $scope.files1);
            var k= 0;
            for(i=0;i<$scope.files1.length;i++)
            {
                     fd.append("file" + ++k, $scope.files1[i]);

            }

Comment: I guess the problem is multer accepts form data as (fieldname, filename) so your fieldname must be unique so I have put that k and incremented it and it worked, I guess there is better way to do it just check

Comment: I want to get the onchange elemtents as unique functions to prove in a working version ithat the two different files are selected. Edited it above. When I try to log the form data in the backend file it gives me an empty array so I think there goes something wrong in the form data sending from the angular controller to the nodejs backend.

Comment: I get the error TypeError: path must be a string or a Buffer.

Comment: it is now working ! changed in the nodejs the var upload = multer({storage:storage}).array(...) to .any() not it works :) thanks for your time